# Ember: Return randomized property value on each reload

Tags: ember.js, random, loading, ember-cli

I have a loading template in which I want to show a random "please wait" message each time the loading route is used, but while the randomness works the first time, the property is then set and doesn't refresh. How do I return a random value each time the route is loaded?

I tried creating a timestamp property and adding that to the watched fields, but again, that property is only set once and then doesn't refresh. I also tried just adding "Date()" to the watch list, and it really didn't like that (understandable since it isn't a field).

Here's my loading controller code:
import Ember from 'ember';

```
//app/controllers/loading.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  loadingText: [
    'Your wish is my command.',
    'Loading, please hang on.',
    'I\'ll be back in two shakes of a lamb\'s tail.',
    'Your request is very important to us...',
    'Hmmmm hmm hmmm...',
    'It shall be as you say...',
    'Let me get that for you.'
  ],

  randLoadingText: Ember.computed('loadingText', function() {
    var loadingText = this.loadingText;
    return (loadingText[Math.floor(Math.random()*loadingText.length)]);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use [volatile](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_cacheable) option on property?

```
//app/controllers/loading.js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  loadingText: [
    'Your wish is my command.',
    'Loading, please hang on.',
    'I\'ll be back in two shakes of a lamb\'s tail.',
    'Your request is very important to us...',
    'Hmmmm hmm hmmm...',
    'It shall be as you say...',
    'Let me get that for you.'
  ],

  randLoadingText: function() {
    var loadingText = this.loadingText;
    return (loadingText[Math.floor(Math.random()*loadingText.length)]);
  }.property().volatile()
});
```

Comment: I realize you're copying his code, but it's likely it should be extending `Controller` and not `ObjectController`.  Great use of volatile.

Comment: Ooo, that's excellent, thanks @griffosx! And a fun function name to boot! @Kingpin2k, should it be just a regular controller because I have no model for a loading route?

Comment: correct, an ObjectController decorates an Object, an ArrayController decorates an Array, a Controller decorates nothing.